# SQL Window Functions- NTH_VALUE- Why does it return NULL if we use Order by for first n-1 rows

Tags: mysql, window-functions

[image]

So, I am talking about the NTH_VALUE(column,n) in SQL

Now What I observed is that if I used to order by clause and specify the same column as inside nth_value, the first n-1 rows are always NULL in the selected column. Why is that?  IF I want to select the 3rd column to say, and the 3rd column exists, it should return the 3rd column for row number 1 and 2 as well in spite of whether I use the order by(same column)  clause or not?
ALso, any way to get around with it?

Answer (score 5):

This happens because the default frame clause that sql uses is **range between unbounded preceding and current row**. This means it will only consider rows till the current row to get the nth value. So for the rows till N-1, you'll get NULL because Nth value is beyond these N-1 rows.

**Solution:**

If you change that to **range between unbounded preceding and unbounded following** inside over() then you won't get NULL values with the Nth value window function.